# Dubai Tourist Visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas, dubai

If my issue date of visa is 2nd Feb and valid until 1st April. So if I enter Dubai on 15th March, will my 30 days period start from 15th March and will be valid until 14th April?

Or do I have to exit Dubai 1st of April?

Answer (score 1):

You have to exit by 1st April, however you can extend the visa twice for up to 30 days each time http://www.dubaivisa.net/uae/duration30days.html

Comment: Do you have a citation for the need to exit by 1st April? Although it [sounds correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) we shouldn't have to take someone's word for it. The link doesn't say anything regarding leaving by the expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

You have to exit Dubai before valid until date. In this case, April 1st.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but could you provide some kind of references to support your position, rather than simply stating it?